# How can I use a `comment` fa-icon and a text div to display the number of messages a user has?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I would like to create a message-counter that would look similar to this [link](http://pokit.org/get/?72fb3565120948dfceac4c34e70cb991.jpg) , using only CSS and HTML.

Let's assume that I have the means of injecting the number of messages using AngularJS, and that I use this code: `<i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i>` to present the message icon. How can I overlay it with a span and put the span element precisely in the corner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use something like below. It's a span (positioned relative), contains the icon and another span which is then positioned absolute.

```
<span class="count-icon">
    <i class="fa fa-2x fa-comment"></i>
    <span class="count">3</span>
</span>
```

And the CSS:

```
.count-icon {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.count {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;

    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;

    background: red;
    border-radius: 8px;

    font-size: 12px;    
    text-align: center;
}
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mX45f/

Comment: That was fast... And exactly what I needed. Thank you, sir!

Answer (score 1):

To take it a step further than Michael Rose's answer.

You can do this without any additional markup at all

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/mX45f/2/)

**HTML**

```
<i class="fa fa-2x fa-comment"></i>
```

**CSS**

```
i {
    position: relative;
}
i.fa-comment:after {
    position: absolute;
    content:"3";
    top: 0;
    right: 0;    
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;    
    background: red;
    border-radius: 8px;    
    font-size: 12px;    
    text-align: center;
}
```